# access denied even though I specified policy.url in java.security

Tags: java, security, exception

I am reading the tutorial on java security by oracle.
(http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep4.html)

I duplicate all the files and everything from the tutorial basically.

I am able to run the file with security manager using the following approach in unix:

```
java -Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=recvPolicy -cp sCount.jar Count ../../test
```

But when I try to specify a new policy.url in the java.security file like this:

```
policy.url.1=file:${java.home}/lib/security/java.policy
policy.url.2=file:${user.home}/.java.policy
policy.url.3=file:/home/myhome/SigningTest/recvPolicy
```

it gives me an exception when I run:

```
java -Djava.security.manager -cp sCount.jar Count ../../test
```

The exception is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.io.FilePermission ../../test read)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:100)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
 at Count.main(Count.java:17)
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I did a quick test of this and it works for me. So the only thing that could be causing this problem (my guess) is that you have two jdks installed on your unix box. So make sure that the "java" that you are using for the command line execution is the same version whose java.security you have modified.

The default sun java 6 security file (if you are using ubuntu) is located at:

```
/etc/java-6-sun/security/java.security
```

So make sure you are editing the correct version of java.security